# get_header() not working in a custom page template

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using a child theme. In my child theme folder I have the following files:

[image: child theme directory structure]

In my custom page template "page-lp3.php" I'm using get_header('blank') to call a custom header template. But no matter what I do, it reverts to the child-theme's header.php file not header-blank.php as intended.

This is the code in "page-lp3.php":

```
<?php

/*
Template Name: LP3
*/

get_header('blank');

?>
```

The custom template is activated for that page in WordPress. And the changes I make to the custom template are working as expected. But the custom header is not cooperating. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just use like this "get_header();" and try

Comment: Maybe it's absurd and you already checked, but better check it again then regret it. Have you checked for file permission? are you sure PHP can actually READ it? If that work you should debug the get_header function i guess

Answer (score 0):

Check the error logs files of your project and removes errors first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do something wrong inside the "header-blank.php"
How to debugging error
1 . Call default header if that come copy default header code into your new header-black.php and check.
2. add die with some message inside new header file and check
3   remove cache of browser